# Exceptions silently swollen when using CralwerRunner of Scrapy

Tags: python, exception, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to use `CrawlerRunner` to run a spider using `Scrapy` as follows:

```
a_crawler = CrawlerRunner(settings)

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    CodeThatGenerateException()
    print("Starting crawler")
    yield a_crawler.crawl(MySpider)
    reactor.stop()

crawl()
reactor.run()
```

Strangely the Exception generated by the first line of the `crawl` function is not printed, nothing happens and the application hangs and does not stop
I cannot figure out what is going on
Any suggestion is welcomed

Comment: Why do you have both `a_crawler` and `serp_crawler`?

Comment: corrected it, it was a mistake

Comment: There's probably an error in the spider. Try to run the spider in another way and check for errors, or run it this way and when it get stuck force stop and see if there are errors.

Comment: It seems the problem happens before the crawler even starts

Comment: OK, then what is the code that generates the exception?